# Problem involving modulus of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $a, b \in \Bbb C$, such that either $|a| = 1$ or $|b| = 1$. Show that $|a-b|\le|a-\bar a b|$.

Comment: That's an interesting problem.  How would you approach it?

Comment: a* means conjugate of a

Comment: please help me to solve the question.

Comment: So I might start by writing $a=x+iy,b=w+iz$, and then seeing what happens.  Is there anything you have already tried?

Comment: ok ahmed if i take less than or equal to sign then how can i solve the question

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:
$$a=e^{i\pi/2}=i, \quad b=e^{i\pi}=-1,$$
one has
$$|a-b|=\sqrt{2}\color{red}{>} |a-\bar{a}b|=0,$$
which makes your claim wrong.

Comment: Show |a-b*|<|a-ab*|,if either |a|=1 or |b|=1
what do you think now boon

Comment: It is still wrong. You can check it easily yourself by finding a counterexample as I did above.